# IF Statement with Loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a quick question. I am new to VBA and I have been stuck with how I should implement an IF statement with a Loop.

I have a range that I wish to select the cell when my input box returns a certain value. For example:

```
Sub Example()
Dim userinput As String
userinput = InputBox("What ID would you like to choose?")
If userinput = "1" Then



End If
End Sub
```

**If userinput equals "1" then I want Range("A10") to be selected**. However, in my sheet, userinput value can be from 1-50 and I don't want to write 49 elseif statements. How can I loop through the range of A10:A86 to return the correct range depending on the userinput?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little inconsistent. Do you want to **select** a cell, or just **get the value** of the cell? Are you choosing among 50 cells (A10:A59), or 77 cells (A10:A86)?

At any rate, I believe that `Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex)` is your answer. It lets you refer a cell based on integer coordinates rather than a string. So, `Cells(10, 1)` refers to cell "A10", `Cells(11, 2)` refers to  cell "B11", and `Cells(userinput + 9, 1)` refers to a cell in column A that is 9 greater than the user input.

(Edit: I've just now realized that your userinput variable is a string, not an integer. So, to use it with `Cells()`, you'll need to convert it with `CLng()`).

Comment: I am choosing among 77 cells. I want the return value in the IF statement to select a cell. But since the userinput value has a big range I am wondering if there is a better way to express what I want the return values in my IF statement to be than multiple elseif clauses.

Comment: @natguy8 `Cells(CLng(userinput) + 9, 1).Select`. If `userinput` is 1, this one line will select cell A10; if it is 2, the line will select cell A11; if it is 3, the line will select cell A12, and so forth. Note that, if you're using this for someone else and not just as a learning exercise, you should also check to see if `userinput` is between 1 and 77 before you use it, and inform the user if they enter a value outside this range. You should also name your variable based on what it holds, like `cellSelection` or something, rather than just a generic `userinput`.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense. How would I put that in a loop so I don't have to repeat that same line of code multiple times?

Comment: @natguy8 You don't. That's what I'm saying, that *one line* will select a cell based on the value of `userinput`. There's no loop required.